# C++11: are 16-byte atomic<> variables automatically aligned on 16-byte boundaries allowing CMPXCHG16B instruction?

Tags: c++, x86-64, memory-alignment, stdatomic, compare-and-swap

Are 16-byte `atomic<>` variables automatically aligned on 16-byte boundaries allowing the compiler/runtime libraries to efficiently use the x86 `CMPXCHG16B` instruction?  Or should we as a matter of style always manually specify `alignas(16)` for all such variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any decent implementation of `std::atomic<>` will use `alignas` itself to make `lock cmpxchg16b` efficient, if the library uses `lock cmpxchg16b` at all instead of a mutex for 16-byte objects.

Not all implementations do, for example I think MSVC's standard library makes 16-byte objects fully non-lock-free using the standard mutex fallback.

**You don't need `alignas(16)` on `atomic<T>`**.

You only need manual alignment for atomics if you have a plain `T` object that you want to use `atomic_ref` on.  `atomic_ref<>` has no mechanism to align an already existing T object.  The current version of the design exposes a `required_alignment` member you should use.  It's up to you to do that for correctness.  (Otherwise you get UB which could mean tearing, or just *extremely* slow system-wide performance for split `lock` RMWs.)

```
 // for atomic_ref<T>
alignas(std::atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment) T sometimes_atomic_var;

 // often equivalent, and doesn't require checking that atomic_ref<T> is supported
alignas(std::atomic<T>) T sometimes_atomic_var;
 // use the same alignment as atomic<T>
```

---

Note that a misaligned `lock cmpxchg16b` split across a cache line boundary would still be atomic but very very slow (same as any `lock`ed instruction: the atomicity guarantee for atomic RMW is not contingent on alignment).  More like an actual bus lock, instead of just a local-to-this-core [cache lock delaying MESI responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num).

Narrower atomics definitely need to be naturally aligned for correctness because pure-load and pure-store can compile to [asm pure load or store where HW guarantees require some alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86).

But 16-byte objects are only guaranteed atomic with `lock cmpxchg16b` so `.load()` and `.store()` have to be implemented with `lock cmpxchg16b`.  (Load with CAS(0,0) to get the old value and either replace 0 with itself or do nothing, and store with a CAS retry loop.  This sucks but is somewhat better than a mutex.  It doesn't have the read-side scalability you'd expect from a lock-free `load`, which is one reason GCC7 and later no longer advertizes `atomic<16-byte-object>` as lock-free, even though it will still use `lock cmpxchg16b` in the libatomic functions it calls instead of inlining `lock cmpxchg16b`)

Comment: Perhaps suggest `static_assert(alignof(std::atomic<...>) >= sizeof(std::atomic<...>));`

Comment: @Acorn: If you're trying to detect libraries that don't internally use `lock cmpxchg16b` at all, then maybe.  e.g. if you're rolling your own atomic accesses to the object sometimes, and need to be sure that compiler-generated accesses are using `lock`ed instructions, not relying on some mutex that you'd ignore.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning in your answer: Linux 5.7 is getting a new option to send `SIGBUS` to processes that try to take a split lock. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6650cdd9a8ccf00555dbbe743d58541ad8feb6a7

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: There's also a perf counter for it on most hardware.  `sq_misc.split_lock`.  But yes, as that kernel patch notes, it's very very bad including for other cores, so much so that other HW features were introduced to detect it.  Terminology note: the lock isn't an object that you "take", it's a modifier on the access.  This is about instructions with a `lock` prefix that do one atomic transaction.

Comment: Yeah, my wording there was a bit sloppy. I meant processes that do a `lock`-prefixed instruction across cache lines that makes the **core** take the global bus lock.

Comment: Manual specification of alignment may be required for `atomic_ref`, as it cannot control its _external_ underlying variable.

Descent implementation of `atomic` will even pad, say, 11 byte underlying type to 16.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: The OP didn't ask about atomic_ref in this question, but yes I guess it would be a good idea.  (And I did recently answer one of the OP's other questions with `atomic_ref` as the answer.)

Comment: ... _and maybe correctness depending on how careful the atomic_ref implementation is_ -- could you please elaborate it in my question, do you think a good implementaion is expected to be correct in this case  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996108/atomic-ref-when-external-underlying-type-is-not-aligned-as-requested

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Last I looked, I don't think `atomic_ref<T>` included a `required_alignment` member.  My earlier phrasing was based on that; updated. 
 Either I missed it or the standards committee only later noticed that atomicity sometimes requires more than `alignof(T)`, and that nobody wants compilers to emit code that checks alignment at runtime to decide whether a specific object is lock-free or not.  (i.e. everyone hates `.is_lock_free()`, loves `.is_always_lock_free`)

Comment: N4861 includes `required_alignment`, so probably it will be in the final standard. I'm trying to contribute `atomic_ref` to MSVC ( https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/843 ), and found out that it is possible to reuse `atomic` implementation for `atomic_ref`, without breaking `atomic` ABI. But runtime fallback for properly-sized but misaligned types makes it _way_ more complicated.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: I'd certainly hope something like `required_alignment` makes it into the final standard!! I wasn't implying that it might not, just that I'd seen an earlier sample implementation of `atomic_ref` a year or more ago that might not have had anything like that, but still blindly assumed alignment of the underlying object.  (Making it unsafe for `int64_t` on 32-bit x86 for example.)  Or like I said, maybe I just missed the existing of a `required_alignment` member and only noticed the safety risk.

Comment: Very informative guys.  With my current sub-project, I'm happy to just use atomic operations even for the phases where I don't need atomic access, and the extra verbosity isn't bad anyway.  I was mostly asking in order to inform my ideas going forward and your extra info over and above my initial question gives me a lot to shape my future direction with.