# atomic_ref when external underlying type size is not power of two

Tags: c++, c++20, stdatomic

TL;DR: Would you expect `atomic_ref<3 bytes struct>` to be non-lock-free, or to achieve lock-free by using CAS or LL/SC on bigger memory amount, if possible?

---

It is continuation of [atomic_ref when external underlying type is not aligned as requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996108/atomic-ref-when-external-underlying-type-is-not-aligned-as-requested) question.

Probably too big for a comment, and not enough related to edit original question.

I think that it may be possible to implement lock-free `atomic_ref<T>` for non natural atomic size. That is non power of two size.

Such `atomic_ref<T>` could access aligned memory as wider type. Most of the time it would have to fallback to compare exchange. Still it will be atomic.

It would correspond cases of T, when an implementation of `atomic<T>` would pad the passed type to nearest atomic size.

I think that [P0091](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0019r8.html) explicitly allows to skip this, and make `atomic_ref<T>` only for natural atomic sizes:

> *Note:* Whether an implementation of atomic is lock free, does not necessarily constrain whether the corresponding implementation of atomic_ref is lock free. *--end note*

But what is expected?

(I understand that compare-exchange is not as efficient as normal store or exchange, still I assume it can be more efficient than lock-based, and with such implementation of `atomic_ref` load may be even implemented as normal load)

---

Example:

```
struct S { char a, b, c; };
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::atomic<S>::is_always_lock_free << '\n'; // I expect true
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::atomic_ref<S>::is_always_lock_free << '\n'; // What should I expect?
```

Comment: "could access aligned memory as wider type" . You could read memory as wider type, but you can't write as wider type, as that would touch bytes that don't belong to the object, and cause a data race (say with another thread that just happens to access a neighboring object).

Comment: "*What should I expect?*" Expect *nothing*. There's a query so that you can write code that can *adapt* as needed.

Comment: `Would you expect` is opinion-based question. `But what is expected?` An architecture and platform dependent value that says if the underlying type is always lock free or not.

Comment: `cmpxchg` does not cause data races if comparand and excahnged value is the same in the place not intended for overwrite.

Comment: I think warn + fallback to locking would be fine.  Users should expect `atomic_ref` to be picky about size / alignment.  I guess if you ever wanted to support this in the future, doing it now would be best to avoid a future ABI incompat in whether access to a 3-byte object needs to respect some lock.

Comment: Yeah, ABI is also an issue, so the final decision should be done on first submission.
(But even for MSVC STL there's occasionally chance to do ABI-breaking changes (with next major version of runtime libraries). Also MSVC's `/std:c++latest` is still treated as _experimental_, which turned out to be an excuse for ABI-breaking of C++20 features)